# Get list items from another server?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using Office 365 and I need to build an app (Sharepoint-hosted) that gets list items from another server. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: from an on premises sharepoint server?

Comment: Yes it is on premises.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint on premises and sharepoint online both expose functionality through REST Services,  from your sharepoint add in you can call using standard $.ajax calls to these services.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx

You still need to read about how to authenticate before calling the services.

Comment: is it possible to use url to the list like this : var siteUrl = "http://w2k12sp02:2222";
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("GP-List").getItems("");

Comment: JSOM doesn't have a way to provide credentials and there are also issues of cross domain requests. REST is the right option here.